# npm install: WARN on dependency

Tags: installation, npm, warnings

I'm using npm install cmd in my TFS build. I always get the following WARN:

`npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.3.1`

How could I delete this warning?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Are you running on Windows or Linux?  If so, `fsevents` cannot be installed, as it is an OSX-only package.

If you run `npm` with `--loglevel=error`, you should no longer see this or any other warnings.  As far as I know, there is no way to selectively suppress warnings in `npm`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I aim to hide this warn, cause TFS interpret this as an error.

Comment: OK, well somewhere in one of your TFS scripts, something is running an `npm install`. you need to change that to `npm --logevel=error install`, and that will suppress the WARN message and Team Foundation Server will stop complaining about it.

Comment: After waiting on angular 4 to install for an hour, I cancelled it, used this parameter, and it installed in about 10 seconds.

Answer (score 14):

The flag `-s` / `--silent` works great if you want to remove all warnings and errors:

```
npm install --silent
```

[npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#shorthands-and-other-cli-niceties)

Answer (score 6):

`npm install --no-optional` prevents this warning