# How to install a forked and customized ionic native cordova plugin without this error?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I am trying to fork a cordova plugin, apply some modifications, and then install it into my Ionic 4 project.

I did the following:

**Step 1:** I forked the plugin to my own Github repo

**Step 2:** I added this plugin successfully to my project using the command: `ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/[MYUSERNAME]/cordova-plugin-speechrecognition --save`.

I can verify that this step went well as my changes are reflected in the `plugins` folder and in `package.json` I observe the link to my repo:

`"cordova-plugin-speechrecognition": "git+https://github.com/[MYUSERNAME]/cordova-plugin-speechrecognition.git"`.

**Step 3:** Then it goes wrong when I try to install this plugin. When I run the command `npm install @ionic-native/speech-recognition` I get the error:

> $ npm install @ionic-native/speech-recognition --save npm WARN
>   ajv-keywords@3.4.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.9.1 but none is
>   installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN
>   ionic-image-loader@7.0.0-beta.2 requires a peer of
>   @ionic-native/file@^5.0.0-beta.21 but none is installed. You must
>   install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN optional SKIPPING
>   OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.8 (node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN
>   notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for
>   fsevents@1.2.8: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
>   {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> - @ionic-native/speech-recognition@5.5.0 updated 1 package and audited 53115 packages in 14.827s
>
> found 2 vulnerabilities (1 low, 1 high) run `npm audit fix` to fix
>   them, or `npm audit` for details

What did I do wrong here and what this error even mean?

Comment: I don't see any errors in your console output. I tend to ignore npm warnings like skipping optional dependecy, as they do not seem to do any harm. There are even Q&As here on StackOverflow on muting warning, eg. https://stackoverflow.com/q/27686889/5730444

Comment: So this is the right way to do it? Changes should be reflected in the build?

Comment: Looks correct to me. Try it out :) You are aware that the `npm install @ionic-native/speech-recognition` will install the original plugin, not your modified/forked version?

Comment: No I am not? How would I then install this custom plugin with npm install?

Comment: See the [npm install docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) or questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509669/how-to-install-an-npm-package-from-github-directly). You'll have to specify the link to **your** Github repo in the npm install command

Answer (score 0):

@ionic-native plugins work in a different way than other Cordova plugins.

They publish the plugin wrappers with npm scripts under their respective URLs. In other words, each plugin wrapper has a corresponding npm package but not a separate Git repo, so you can’t refer to to individual wrappers via Github URLs directly (in your package.json file).

Possible workarounds are:

1. Copy @ionic-native plugin package locally, make changes, add to your Git repo, and install your modified npm package locally with npm install /path/to/your/folder
2. Fork the plugin on Github, make changes (optionally: submit a Pull request), publish the modified plugin as a separate npm package