# Getting npm WARN deprecated

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, npm-install, package.json

I am getting following npm WARN deprecated although these packages are not in package.json file. Where these packages are listed? and where should i change their versions?

```
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.9: One of your dependencies needs to upgrade to fsevents v2: 1) Proper nodejs v10+ support 2) No more fetching binaries from AWS, smaller package size
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.10: core-js@<3.0 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
```

Comment: If you want to hide this warn, you just need to install fsevents as a optional dependency. Just execute:

npm i fsevents@latest -f --save-optional
..And the warn will no longer be a bother.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with deprecation warnings from npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38889519/how-to-deal-with-deprecation-warnings-from-npm)

Answer (score 3):

If these packages are not in your package.json, then they must be in package-lock.json which maintains the dependencies of dependencies mentioned in your package.json .

You can simply update the packages which are giving warning. Or maybe you can suppress these warning messages, npm gives various options to do it. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27686889/npm-install-warn-on-dependency).

Answer (score 1):

These packages are not listed because they are dependencies of other packages that you use, they are not in your json file but some of the packages that are using them need them.

I don't think you have any problems updating them, but I recommend saving your status anyway. You can update your project on github up to this point, and if something happens with the update you can always go back to the previous point.

Comment: if you want, it is not problem