# How to get rid of "npm WARN eslint-config-react-app@5.2.0 requires a peer of eslint-plugin-flowtype@3.x but none is installed" warning

Tags: reactjs

I have created an react app using

```
create-react-app pics
```

command. But unfortunately I got some warnings. How can I get rid of these warnings?

```
npm WARN eslint-config-react-app@5.2.0 requires a peer of eslint-plugin-flowtype@3.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.2 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules/jest-haste-map/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are warnings about optional dependencies and peer dependencies. If things nevertheless work, you can ignore them.

Answer (score 1):

Use this command:
npm i eslint-plugin-flowtype@3.x

Answer (score 1):

You can look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27686889/npm-install-warn-on-dependency) for more info on how to get rid of those warnings.

You could either do `npm install eslint-plugin-flowtype@3.x` to address the problem at hand or with the command `create-react-app pics`, append a `-s` meaning silent among others (--loglevel=error, etc.) to suppress the warnings. `create-react-app pics -s` (Remember the errors are valid, just not shown on the terminal anymore.)